# Разница 2 тегов HTML

Tags: html, вёрстка, теги

В чем разница тега HTML `<article>` и `<section>`? Какую в них хранить информацию? Могут ли они хранить в себе теги `<header>` и `footer`?

Comment: А зачем тебе `header  и footer`  в `article и section`?  Это не верное решение.  `header  и footer` для того и были созданы в месте с `main`, чтобы обозначить структуру  страницы
Почитай, это про  footer -  https://webref.ru/html/footer

Comment: это про  header-  https://webref.ru/html/header

Comment: это про article- https://webref.ru/html/section

Comment: это про section- https://webref.ru/html/section

Comment: Ответ написать можно, но не думаю, что 4 строчки заслуживают ответа...А если писать подробно, то это уже не ответ получиться,  а целое учебное пособие по `html`, но это не тот ресурс...

Comment: @Air, (Это не верное решение.) приведённые вами ссылки не подтверждают ваших слов.

Comment: ))))))))))))))))  ок.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Множество тегов были добавлены в стандарт HTML, чтобы разметка стала более понятной для устройств наподобие "screen reader" и роботов, которые сканируют страницы. Цель сделать разметку "более семантичной".  Устройство должно сразу понять: где навигация, где основа, где контент.

Была сделана попытка уйти от `div`, или по крайней мере предоставить альтернативу. Но из-за достаточной сложности вёрстки (дизайна, совместимости и т.д) это не получилось на 100%, совместимый, чистый код, с ограниченными вложениями и правильной семантикой, создавать трудно.

- `<article>` - элемент контента, содержания
- `<section>` - структурный элемент, отдельная секция, разметка

Универсальность элементов создала множество трактовок использования. Так например `header` и `footer` могут использоваться в разных элементах (с некоторыми ограничениями). И `article` и `section` могут содержать `header` и `footer`.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- многоуровневое вложение элементов для стилизации -->

<section class="hero is-info">
 <div class="hero-body">
   <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title">Hero</h1>
   </div>
 </div>
</section>

<!-- пример article -->
<article class="forecast content">
    <h1>Weather forecast for Seattle</h1>
    <article class="day-forecast">
        <h2>03 March 2018</h2>
        <p>Rain.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day-forecast">
        <h2>04 March 2018</h2>
        <p>Periods of rain.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day-forecast">
        <h2>05 March 2018</h2>
        <p>Heavy rain.</p>
    </article>
</article>

<!-- Пример с использование section -->

<article class="content">
    <hgroup>
        <h1>Fishing for Beginners</h1>
        <h2>A getting-started guide</h2>
    </hgroup>
    <section>
        <h1>Introduction</h1>
        <p>People have been catching fish for food since before recorded history...</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1>Equipment</h1>
        <p>The first thing you'll need is a fishing rod or pole that you find comfortable and is strong enough for the kind of fish you're expecting to try to land...</p>
    </section>
</article>
```

- [`<article>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article) (Mozilla)
- [`<section>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) (Mozilla)
- [W3C `<header>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element) с примерами использования
- [W3C `<footer>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-footer-element) с примерами использования

Answer (score 1):

https://html5book.ru/html5-semantic-elements

по моему мнению, грамотная статья, достаточно подробно раскрывающая тему html5 элементов

https://validator.w3.org/nu/

а это валидатор от `w3c`